# Python server interaction

Tags: python, client-server, messaging

I'm new to python so please excuse me if question doesn't make sense in advance.

We have a python messaging server which has one file server.py with main function in it. It also has a class "*server" and main defines a global instance of this class, "the_server". All other functions in same file or diff modules (in same dir) import this instance as "from **main** import the_server".

Now, my job is to devise a mechanism which allows us to get latest message status (number of messages etc.) from the aforementioned messaging server.

This is the dir structure:
src/ -> all .py files only one file has main

In the same directory I created another status server with main function listening for connections on a different port and I'm hoping that every time a client asks me for message status I can invoke function(s) on my messaging server which returns the expected numbers.

How can I import the global instance, "the_server" in my status server or rather is it the right way to go?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code relating to your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use a single server and design a protocol that supports several kinds of messages. 'send' messages get sent, 'recv' message read any existing message, 'status' messages get the server status, 'stop' messages shut it down, etc.

You might look at existing protocols such as REST, for ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your "status server" and "real server" are running in the same process (that is, loosely, one of them imports the other and starts it), just `from main import the_server` in your status server isn't going to help. That will just give you a new, completely independent instance of `the_server` that isn't doing anything, which you can then report status on.

There are a few obvious ways to solve the problem.

- Merge the status server into the real server completely, by expanding the existing protocol to handle status-related requests, as Peter Wooster suggestions.
- Merge the status server into the real server async I/O implementation, but still listening on two different ports, with different protocol handlers for each.
- Merge the status server into the real server process, but with a separate async I/O implementation.
- Store the status information in, e.g., a `mmap` or a `multiprocessing.Array` instead of directly in the `Server` object, so the status server can open the same `mmap`/etc. and read from it. (You *might* be able to put the `Server` object itself in shared memory, but I wouldn't recommend this even if you could make it work.)

I could make these more concrete if you explained how you're dealing with async I/O in the server today. Select (or poll/kqueue/epoll) loop? Thread per connection? Magical greenlets? Non-magical cooperative threading (like PEP 3156/tulip)? Even just "All I know is that we're using `twisted`/`tornado`/`gevent`/etc., so whatever that does" is enough.

Comment: That's a good synopsis, as you can see from my answer, I prefer a single server, single port, probably mult-threaded RESTful server.

Comment: @PeterWooster: If the original main server isn't RESTful, it's a bit silly to redesign everything just to add a status server. Replacing a working event-loop design with a multithreaded design just to add a status server would be even sillier (especially since it would probably drop your max connections from 10K to 1K…). So, why put those kinds of restrictions onto the solution space when they aren't at all necessary?

Comment: They weren't meant as restrictions, just preferences.  I suspect the current design isn't complete, but then I may be wrong on that, the OP wasn't clear.